# ScaleType crash while supportFinishAfterTransition()

Tags: android, imageview, android-support-library, android-appcompat, scaletype

I'm experiencing a crash when I zoom out a transition with `supportFinishAfterTransition();`. I've been struggling myself for almost 2h without coming out with any fix. Help is much appreciated! Do you have any clue?

Thanks in advance!

```
08-13 09:31:43.375    2490-3109/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.adeya.android, PID: 2490
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: The ImageView's ScaleType has been changed since attaching a PhotoViewAttacher
            at uk.co.senab.photoview.PhotoViewAttacher.checkImageViewScaleType(PhotoViewAttacher.java:707)
            at uk.co.senab.photoview.PhotoViewAttacher.setImageViewMatrix(PhotoViewAttacher.java:821)
            at uk.co.senab.photoview.PhotoViewAttacher.resetMatrix(PhotoViewAttacher.java:813)
            at uk.co.senab.photoview.PhotoViewAttacher.updateBaseMatrix(PhotoViewAttacher.java:898)
            at uk.co.senab.photoview.PhotoViewAttacher.onGlobalLayout(PhotoViewAttacher.java:426)
            at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnGlobalLayout(ViewTreeObserver.java:863)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2059)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1180)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6558)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:777)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:590)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:560)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:763)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5832)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
```

Comment: Try to find out where you set or change the scaletype. As the error reports you change the scale type which not seems to be allowed at this state.

Comment: In the beginning I thought as you say and I started to check around. But I think I'm not changing the scaletype anywhere. I just set it once with picasso.

Comment: Can you debug the line where the scaletype is set? Maybe you get an idea where it comes from.

Answer (score 1):

Been a long time, But incase someone still faces this issue:
You should've called cleanUp() before finishing the activity:

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    mAttacher.cleanup();
}
```